# how to kill Activity permanetly After button click Using Shared prefrance

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button btn1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent newpage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhonrRegistaion.class);
        startActivity(newpage);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myintent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,nextActvity.class);

                startActivities(null);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is my Activity i want moving from one Activity to another Activity i want to kill my Activity permanently using shared prefrances means if open Application then it should launch second Activity . please help i dont know how to kill Activity using shred prefrances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the complete solution

```
//firstly when you register the user set the shared preferences in your register class like this
    //declare pref editor 
            SharedPreferences prefs; 
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

    //paste below peace of code when the registration will be success

                     prefsEditor.putString("register", "yes");
                 prefsEditor.commit(); 

//now in your first activity you just check the shared pref value to know the user is register or no 


 SharedPreferences prefs;
String register;
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        register=prefs.getString("register", "");
//now check the value of shared pref and apply the condition like this
Intent intent ;
    if(register.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, NextAct.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
            else
            {
             intent = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "kill" an activity but you can [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) it.

Comment: finish permanently means next when i Launch app then it should open next not first Activity

Comment: Like registration Page Session Management i need to do that once i will registration then Acclivity should diaper for foreever

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` create condition:

```
if (<your condition>) {
  startActivity(...);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: finish permanently means next when i Launch app then it should open next not first Activity

Comment: I've already written solution. Or create an activity, which doesn't have UI and after running the app will be open first or second activity.

Comment: what i will Put in condition i have only On Button in that Activity ?

Comment: in first Activity only on Button is there and in Second Activity there  is list-view i have to remove first Activity but first time it will come when i install and lunch and click that button like registration page Activity once registered then it disappear na like that

Answer (score 0):

Either finish the old activity when the new one is started:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(LOC_PREF_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
     Boolean startSecond = prefs.getBoolean("StartSecondActivty", false);

         if (startSecond) {
             Intent newpage = new Intent(this, PhonrRegistaion.class);
             startActivity(newpage);
             finish();
        }

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent myintent=new Intent(this, nextActvity.class);

                    startActivities(null);
                    finish();

                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                LOC_PREF_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("StartSecondActivty", true);
                editor.commit();
                editor.apply();

                }
           });

    }
}
```

This is not permanent as such as it will reside in memory until GC.

If you want to permanently kill you activity (and app) try killing your own process:

```
    // Kill everything you can
    public void killMyProcess() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "/system/bin/kill -9 -1");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            reader.close();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have to kill Process like registration page once u ll registration than registration Activity disappear we need set flag for that using shared preference i need that Actually

Comment: OK, see my updated reply. Start the second activity, finish the first, save a boolean that you check when you start the first to determine whether to directly start the next one.

Comment: LOC_PREF_FILE what is this yes i want like please tell what is LOC_PREF_FILE?

Comment: thanx Andy this i wanted actually

Comment: andy the method u gave is for killing the Process?

Comment: You don't have to have to kill the process, but if you want to, use that function. LOC_PREF_FILE is the name and location of the pref file.