# Change the first layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to display a layout that takes user information and save them.
Then, when the user open the application for second time it shows different layout. 
How i can do that??

and Please if you can help by just mentioning the right keywords so i can also search by myself I will be great-full

Comment: Hint: `Fragments` and `SharedPreference`. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261240/how-to-kill-activity-permanetly-after-button-click-using-shared-prefrance/23262571#23262571

here is my answer for same question you can use the same approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `onCreate()` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            boolean firstStart = getSharedPreferences("SomeName", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstStart", true);

        if(!firstStart){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


}
```

Make sure you write false to the shared prefferences after your first start:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("SomeName", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putBoolean("firtStart", false);
edit.apply();
```

Comment: @user3551480 If you got it to work in your application, could you accept my answer? If it doesn't work yet, let me know!